# MYSQL Data query is not Refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Iam having this HTML application which insert some info into a database dyanmically using arrays and retrieve same data in the same table..What is happing is that when i click on sumbit it goes to the insert.php page and then refreshes back to the add.php page,when it refreshed back to the add.php page the new data added would appear unless i refresh the add.php page again so it will retreive the new data.

i want the data added without refreshing the page agian.

Any Adive.
Code Below*
Thank you...

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Settings Administration</title>
    <?php

        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $username="user"; // Mysql username 
        $password="password"; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="db"; // Database name 
        $tbl_name="table"; // Table name 
        // Connect to server and select database.

        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 

        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        ?>

    <script>
        var originalCount = 1;
        var realCount = 0;
        function removeRowFromTable()
        {
            try
            {
                var table = document.getElementById('SlideTable');
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

                for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
                {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
                    {
                        if(rowCount <= 1)
                        {
                            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                            break;
                        }
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(e)
            {
            alert(e);
            }
        }

        function addRowToTable()
        {

            var table = document.getElementById('SlideTable');

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            //Used for reference only
            realCount = rowCount;

            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.checked = false;
            element1.name="chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);


            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.value = "30";
            element2.size = 10;
            element2.name = "slideTime[]";
            cell2.appendChild(element2);

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var element3 = document.createElement("input");
            element3.type = "text";
            element3.value = "/path";
            element3.size = 50;
            element3.name = "slideSource[]";
            cell3.appendChild(element3);


              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var element4 = document.createElement("input");
            element4.type = "text";
            element4.value = "/path";
            element4.size = 50;
            element4.name = "slideComment[]";
            cell4.appendChild(element4);

            // To keep track of index
            originalCount = originalCount + 1;
        }

        function validateRow(frm)
        {
             var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i)
            {
                if(inputs[i].type == 'text')
                   if(inputs[i].value == '') 
                   {
                      alert("Form could not be sent. All text fields should be NOT empty.");
                      return;
                   }
            }

            // submit
            frm.submit();
        }

        function setNumberOfSlides()
        {
            document.getElementById('numberOfSlides').value=realCount;
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <h1>Fill the slides in this table</h1>
        </p>
        <table id="SlideTable" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Select to Remove</td>
                <td>Slide Time (sec)</td>
                <td>Slide Source</td>
                <td>Slide Comment</td>
            </tr>
            <? while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
                <td><input size=10 name="slideTime[]" type="text" id="slideTime" value="<? echo $rows['SlideTime']; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input size=50 name="slideSource[]" type="text" id="slideSource" value="<? echo $rows['SlideSource']; ?>"/></td>
                <td><input size=50 name="slideComment[]" type="text" id="slideComment" value="<? echo $rows['SlideComment']; ?>"/></td>

            </tr>
            <? } ?>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="button" size="15" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" />
            <input type="button" size="15" value="Remove" onclick="removeRowFromTable();" />
            <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Refresh">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="button" size="35" value="Submit" onclick="validateRow(this.form);" />
        </p>
        <input type="hidden" id="numberOfSlides" name="NumberOfSlides" value="">
    </form>
          <?php
        mysql_close(); //close database
        ?>
</body>
```

### Insert.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=http://www.h2os.com.au/add.php">
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name 
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Delete all the old data
$old_data_sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name";
mysql_query($old_data_sql);

$slideTimeArray;
$slideSourceArray;
$slideCommentArray;
foreach ($_POST['slideTime'] as $i => $value) 
{
    $slideTimeArray[]=$value;
}

foreach ($_POST['slideSource'] as $i => $value) 
{
    $slideSourceArray[]=$value;
}
foreach ($_POST['slideComment'] as $i => $value) 
{
    $slideCommentArray[]=$value;
}

// String to add values
$values_sql="";
for($k=0;$k<count($slideTimeArray);++$k)
{
    $values_sql .= "             ('$slideTimeArray[$k]','$slideSourceArray[$k]','$slideCommentArray[$k]') ";
    if($k==count($slideTimeArray)-1)
        $values_sql .= "; ";
    else
    $values_sql .= ", ";
}

// Insert in the database
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(SlideTime,SlideSource,SlideComment) Values".$values_sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-size: x-large;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center" class="style1">
  <p>Your new Slide show Settings is saved...You Can Check the New settings by clicking             The View Settings Button.</p>
      <p>Thank you</p>
  >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its online on www.h2os.com.au/add.php

Comment: Doesn't seem to require a refresh for me.

Comment: Hello Daniel, Did you tried to submit new data?

Comment: works for me too, you should user mysqli_ instead of mysql_

Comment: Sooo Weird iam trying it now and its not working, did you submit a new data .. and when it refreshes back from the insert.php page to the add.php page the new row youve inserted was displayed ???

Comment: @user2600543 I did submit new data, and yes when i was redirected to add.php my new data was there and did not require a refresh.

Comment: Really iam so confused its not working here....

Comment: Perhaps a browser caching issue?

Comment: i deleted my cache iam using also chrome...iam soo confused.